# railscast #250 Authentication / password cannot be NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

im getting this error message when i submit signup form:
(im following railscast #250 http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch)

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'password' cannot be null: 
INSERT INTO `users` (`activated`, `activation_key`, ... , `email`, `password`, `password_salt`, `telephone`, `updated_at`) 
VALUES (0, '9cli91cjwmt1rcahaiyefh05xhwy5hvz', ..., 'name@domain.tld', NULL, '$2a$10$4vc0HksIm17rzKDxcYVQiO', 123456789, '2013-06-27 19:16:54')

**Parameters**
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"DNEv4SuXt5btf+MTqM1xA6BWeT7JUa3OAf4AITFCe18=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"name@domain.tld",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "telephone"=>"123456789",
 "activation_key"=>"9cli91cjwmt1rcahaiyefh05xhwy5hvz"},
 "commit"=>"Create User"}
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    ...**
```

i have password value FILTERED in parameter because i use f.password_field.. and therefore i have NULL in SQL command.. f.text_field in email works.. what am i missing ?

only different thing from railscast is i have this in UsersController but it should work

```
def create
  params[:user][:activation_key] = Array.new(32){Random.new.rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Thank you

EDIT:
in Debug @user.inspect
throw this value

```
#<User id: nil, address_id: nil, company_id: nil, email: "username@domain.tld", password: nil, telephone: 123456789, activation_key: "jolkxv5bd7c2zgq08tkvb7srwe20tfqc", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, activated: false, password_salt: nil, password_hash: nil>
```

i had commented
before_save :encrypt_password
now password_hash and password_salt are generated but password column still NULL :(
i tried new app from scratch and it works.. but im not able to solve this ?

Comment: Can you please put this line after creating the user and add the server log output of the full request please:

puts @user.inspect

Comment: i tried (inside create method in Users Controller before if @user.save)
logger.debug "User inspect: #{@user.inspect}"
and
render :text => @some_object.inspect
but nothing happened

Comment: okay in debug @user.inspect throw same values as mysql INSERT, what now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it, this railscast doesnt use password column ! it uses only: `email:string`, `password_hash:string`, `password_salt:string`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is going wrong with your application, but the Railscast you are referring to is kinda dated because nowadays you would use `has_secure_password`. There is a revised episode of that Railscast, but only paying customers can see the revised episodes.

Of course, nothing keeps you from doing authentication without that new method, and I don't think there is any particular disadvantage in doing so, but if you want to check out how `has_secure_password` works, [look at this little tutorial](http://www.millwoodonline.co.uk/blog/using-hassecurepassword-for-rails-authentication).